# Value error in pig latin function code list.remove(x) x not in list when x clearly is in list

Tags: python-3.x, string, function

Writing a pig latin function that takes in text and returns the pig latin translation. Trying to remove the front consonants, but get the ValueError that list.remove(x) x not in list. Print statements show that this is not true.

I wrote a similar program when the input was a single word v.s. text with more than one word. The program worked fine with a one word input, but when I try to modify for more than one word input.

I've tried making a copy of the word that I am trying to modify in case removing letters was messing up the iteration. This doesn't seem to help and I still get the same error when trying to remove the letters.

---

```
def is_consonant(character):

    """takes a character and returns True if it is a consonant"""
    is_cons = False
    if character not in "aeiou":
        is_cons = True
    return is_cons

def to_piglatin(text):

    """takes a word and translates it into pig latin"""
    #convert input to list of lower case letters
    x = text.lower().split()
    print(x)
    if len(x) > 1:
        for word in x:
            front_cons = []
            word_as_list = [word]
            print("word_as_list =", word_as_list)
            for letter in word:
                if is_consonant(letter) == True:
                    print("letter =", letter)
                    front_cons.append(letter)
                    word_as_list.remove(letter)
                else:
                    break
            [word_as_list.append(front_cons[c]) for c in range(0, len(front_cons))]
            word_as_list.append("a")
            word_as_list.append("y")
            print(word_as_list)

test = "Hello there"

to_piglatin(test)
```

[image: print error]

---

I expect the output to be ellohay erethay but I get a Value Error list.remove(x) x not in list.

print statements show that word_as_list = ['hello'] and letter = h
but word_as_list.remove(letter) returns the ValueError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
word_as_list = [word]
```

makes a length 1 list with item `word = 'hello'` not the list of characters. You should modify this into:

```
word_as_list = list(word)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!